# dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (dependency problems)?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, dpkg

When I try to install mysql-server, an error comes like:

```
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What does it mean. Any ideas?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

`dpkg` returning an error code 1 doesn't mean anything specific but it usually has to do with dependency issues. In your case, you tried to install two versions/instances of the same package i.e. `mysql-server`  and `mysql-server-5.7`. So do the following to remove any redundant dependency issues and install a functioning mysql package

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get purge mysql*
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.7
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

this should fix the problem at hand. But in the future, have care about the package names you add after `sudo apt-get install`  since the wrong list of package names - for example redundant entries in the list - results in failure to install either of the packages or worse - you might even find yourself wading through the hellish depths of #DEPENDENCY-HELL

Comment: I like how you run `apt clean` before all else, this should be evangelized. Too many tutorials say to purge packages, `apt update` or force install, or etc and then run `apt autoclean` afterwards, which is sometimes pointless (backwards and/or less effective) because the package cache should be emptied out BEFORE proceeding with reinstall, etc...

Comment: `sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.7` should be done by `sudo apt-get install -f`, shouldn't it? Was the case on my machine at least.

Comment: If server is low on RAM, please see VPS answer further down. (Running mysql + apt upgrade => mysql crash)

Answer (score 27):

All of the answers I've been able to find for this question have been of the form "purge your Mysql install and re-install it." But in my case, I already have a working/active Mysql install. For me, the reason why `dpkg --configure -a` fails is because Mysql is already installed. Why dpkg thinks that the postinstall script needs to be run for my already-installed-and-upgraded Mysql I may never know, but it does.

After considerable time scouring for answers, I found a solution that should work if there are others who already have a working Mysql 5.7 and just want to get past this bogus postinstall script. You can edit the postinstall script directly as (on Ubuntu):

`sudo vi /var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.7.postinst`

And then, on the second line, just add `exit 0` and then run `dpkg` again and you should get something like:

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a         
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.28-0ubuntu0.18.04.4) ...
```

You definitely would not want to follow these instructions if your Mysql installation had not previously completed (there's a reason that the postinstall script insists on running). But for those who might end up with dpkg in a wonky state, as I have, the above can save you a lot of time purging and reinstalling an already-working version of Mysql.

Comment: This solved the issue for me, thanks!  I had ssh crash mid upgrade and like a dummy wasn't using screen.   So when I logged back in, the post install didn't want to work.

Comment: It seems the original question (error message) is a general one. For me, this answer is the one that solved the problem. Cleaning up everything and reinstalling does not solve my problem, and introduces additional task of restoring the database.

Comment: This solved the problem for me too.

Comment: Yeah, this was the solution for me!

Answer (score 14):

This should help

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

And now reinstall mysql

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Answer (score 9):

If you're on a VPS or similar, your error may be due to lack of RAM.

Running apt-upgrade seems to require some RAM, so it may force-close mysql, hence the problem to recover from the error.

Try:

1) Stop mysql manually before any apt-upgrade

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

2) Fix:

```
sudo dpkg --configure mysql-server-X.X
```

(if version not known, use just mysql-server to **find out** (will not fix error)

3) Check:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Start mysql manually if it wasn't started by apt.

Comment: You right. i used VPN 1.5 GB ram in Google cloud Compute is work. but not with free tier < 1 GB

Answer (score 5):

i face same error due to problem in my upgrade from ubuntu 18.04 to ubuntu 20.04  ,  what i did is get mariadb instead  also make sure  when you do pruge  mysql  that if asked you to remove dbs in the dir
tell it not to delete the dbs so you will  have your old databases  with no data loss

what i did  was  this cmds

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install mariadb-server
```

Answer (score 4):

My answer from [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1084754/610139).

#### New Answer

kill the `musql` deamon and purging helps

```bash
sudo pkill mysqld # kill
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server-5.7 # Or whatever you are trying to purge.
```

Thanks, @endrias for the suggestion.

#### Old Answer

None of the `apt` methods worked for me, try this:

**Find locking process**

```
$ ps -eaf
root      7316     1  0 00:19 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/dpkg --status-fd 35 --configure --pending
root      7808  7316  0 00:19 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/perl -w /usr/share/debconf/frontend /var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-se
root      7817  7808  0 00:19 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash /var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.7.postinst configure
mysql     7973  7817  0 00:20 ?        00:00:00 mysqld --user=mysql --init-file=/var/lib/mysql-files/tmp.iNyY06ty0K --so
```

**Kill it**

do `sudo kill -9 7973`, basically the `mysql` one.

**Now purge**

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server-5.7 # Or whatever you are trying to purge.
```

Comment: if a running `mysql` process is preventing any fixes, you can use `sudo pkill mysql` to kill the `mysql` daemon instead of going the roundabout way of getting the `PID` from the output of `ps -eaf`, `pkill` does the `PID` getting for you.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue. This is how I fixed mine.

1. Restart MySQL service `sudo service mysql restart`
2. Then fix broken installations `sudo apt install -f`

Answer (score 2):

I tried almost every possible way but nothing was working for me. Then I found the problem that I was facing was due to less available ram. You can check your current ram status by `free -h` (in my case available was less than 1 GB). To clear ram restart your device. Then type following commands

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

then again install mysql-server by

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Answer (score 1):

try this solution using **aptitude** this will replace all the file corrupted.

This is work on my 18.04

cr. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/mysql-installation-error-dpkg-error-processing-package-mysql-server-5-5-configure?answer=61604

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to run:

```
systemctl stop mysql.service
```

to stop MySQL before being able to install mysql without errors using:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve the dependency issue, try:

```
sudo apt-get purge
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get check
```

And reinstall the package again by: `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`.

<sup>Source: [Thread: Dpkg: Dependency problems - leaving unconfigured](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2194425).</sup>

Other commands to try:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Related: [How can I Resolve dpkg dependency?](https://askubuntu.com/q/252777/78223) at *Ask Ubuntu*.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be much simpler (in my case) I had a missconfigured value in my configuration file [my.cnf] which lead to the error. 
After cleaning up my.cnf mysql-server was restarted successfully

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on Debian 10, you need to first install GNUPG:

```
sudo apt-get install gnupg
```

That's all; now you can try `dpkg` again.

Answer (score 0):

Also pay attention to the terminal you are using, if it is ZSH many uninstall commands will not work like: `sudo apt-get purge mysql*` and the reinstallation process will fail, to fix this it is simple type in your terminal the word bash so that the terminal used is Bash, run the `sudo apt-get purge mysql*` command again and also the following commands below to confirm that you removed everything.

```
sudo apt-get remove mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql
```

Finally, run `mysql --version` to make sure there is no version on your machine and you can try installing again.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the yes Unix binary, which is incredibly stupid: it just endlessly types y (try it, you can just run yes in your terminal)

so the following just works (I used this in a dockerfile)

```
yes | apt-get install mysql-community-server
```

Answer (score 0):

I had another mysql process running in background.
(ckeck if your lampp mysql server is on, Then turn it off.)
then try
**sudo apt dist-upgrade**

if lammp mysql is not working then,
check this command,
**ps -eaf**
and then look for mysql process and kill it by it's port number
**sudo kill -9**

Answer (score -1):

I was in the same situation. After completely removing MySQL, I reinstalled it, killed the PID using port 3306, and reinstalled MySQL again. It's working now.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score -1):

1.**Check for Dependencies:**

Ensure that all dependencies required by MySQL Server are installed. You can use the following command to install any missing dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

2.**Purge Existing MySQL Packages:**

Try purging the existing MySQL packages before attempting a fresh installation. Note that this will remove MySQL and its configuration files:

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common mysql-server-core-* mysql-client-core-*
```

3.**Remove Configuration Files:**

After purging, make sure to remove the MySQL configuration files:

4.**Update Package Lists:**
Ensure that your package lists are up to date:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

5.**Install MySQL Server:**
After purging, try installing MySQL Server again:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

6.**Configure MySQL Server:**
During the installation, you might be prompted to set a root password and configure other settings. Follow the prompts to complete the installation.

7.**Check for Specific Errors:**

Examine the detailed error messages during the installation process. These messages can provide insights into the specific issues.

8.**Manually Remove Lock Files:**

Remove any existing lock files that might be causing issues:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```

After trying these steps, attempt to install MySQL Server again. If you encounter any specific error messages, please provide those details, and I can offer more targeted assistance.