# Can't install mysql on pure ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I just installed WSL Ubuntu 20.04 and the first thing I've done is

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get upgrade
 sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

and here what it gave me

```
Setting up mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
 * Stopping MySQL database server mysqld                                                                                                                         [ OK ]
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
Cannot open /proc/net/unix: No such file or directory
Cannot stat file /proc/1/fd/5: Operation not permitted
Cannot stat file /proc/1/fd/10: Operation not permitted
Cannot stat file /proc/1/fd/6: Operation not permitted
Cannot stat file /proc/42/fd/7: Operation not permitted
Cannot stat file /proc/42/fd/10: Operation not permitted
Cannot stat file /proc/42/fd/5: Operation not permitted
mysqld will log errors to /var/log/mysql/error.log
mysqld is running as pid 3726
sleep: cannot read realtime clock: Invalid argument
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
```

and

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:

```
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-8.0; however:
  Package mysql-server-8.0 is not configured yet.

    dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    Setting up libcgi-pm-perl (4.46-1) ...
    No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                              Setting up libhtml-template-perl (2.97-1) ...
    Setting up libcgi-fast-perl (1:2.15-1) ...
    Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.1) ...
    Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
    Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9) ...
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     mysql-server-8.0
     mysql-server
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

then I tried `sudo mysql_secure_installation`

`Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

And this is not only on WSL.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem as you; I did the following using `Ubuntu 20.04 WSL` version in *Windows 10* and it helped me.
First, because of the `dependency problems - leaving unconfigured` error, I followed [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44813428/1119621) to purge *MySQL* and attempt a reinstall:

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Having done that the problem remained (but certainly this was helpful anyway).

The next clue was the `Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket` error... The *MySQL* command is asking a password and providing the wrong one results in this error. The password hasn't been set yet, right? Wrong! Reading the [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual - Default Privileges](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/default-privileges.html) the installation sets a random password initially. So the *root* password has to be changed first.

To do so I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26233939/1119621). I copy that answer here for convenience:

*On ubuntu I did the following:*

```
sudo service mysql stop
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-syslog --skip-networking
```

*Then run mysql in a new terminal:*

```
mysql -u root
```

*And run the following queries to change the password:*

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('password') WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

*In MySQL 5.7, the password field in mysql.user table field was removed, now the field name is 'authentication_string'.*

Having quoted the answer, please note the `PASSWORD()` function has been deprecated as shared in [this answer over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52320680/1119621). As stated there, just replace it using any of the [MySQL encryption functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html) I used `MD5()`.

Finally:

```
sudo service mysql start
* Starting MySQL database server mysqld                     [ OK ]
```

Answer (score 4):

**As the first step try these steps**

`sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*`

`sudo apt-get purge mysql*`

`sudo apt-get autoremove`

`sudo apt-get autoclean`

`sudo apt-get remove dbconfig-mysql`

`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

If you get the same error try to **remove MySQL dpkgs**. To do so try these steps

`dpkg -l | grep mysql`

Then you will see the mysql packages and **remove them one by one**

`sudo apt purge [package_name]`

or

`sudo dpkg purge [package_name]`

Although some pkgs won't be removed.Keep them as it is and try to **install mysql server** again.

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt install mysql-server`

`sudo mysql_secure_installation`

Hope you got the answer.
Thank you.

Comment: Great. @AliHelmy

Comment: Guys, be very careful with "--purge mysql*" it will remove other libs like in my case these commands remove all of my php installation's php-mysql extensions.

Comment: @Ain yes this is pure installation. So all the caches and dbs will be deleted related to mysql.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue on a fresh VPS. I resolved it by adding some swap space

```
# Add swap space on Ubuntu 20 (1000MB)
sudo fallocate -l 1G /swapfile
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bak
echo '/swapfile none swap sw 0 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=10
```

then running

```
sudo apt-get install -y mysql-server
```

This workaround could work for WSL, too.

Comment: Please share more details. How does a VPS relate to WSL?

Comment: It seems to be a general issue with ubuntu and mysql-server and I solved it on a VPS and it could work for WSL, too.

Answer (score 0):

when installation freezes

```
> sudo killall mysqld
```

and continue  install